# Import a package-module from inside and outside the package

Tags: python, package, python-import

I got a question about using import in Python. Of course I searched here and elsewhere
on Internet, but could not find a situation comparable to mine. Of course that can be some
hint I am doing something that you better not do...

I got a project which is some kind of test-suite for several devices. For each
device I created a dedicated Python script. I put all these scripts in a package.
I can import this package into another Python script and this way test several
devices in one time. Through a config file I can set which devices I like to test
(together with other necessary information for each device).

Below is a simplified version of the project structure:

```
/app
  app.py
  app.config
  /scripts
    __init__.py
    commmon.py
    script1.py
    script2.py
```

app.py is importing `script1` and `script2` from package `scripts`. Inside the package
there is a module `common.py` with some methods used by all the scripts in the package.

Let's take `script1.py` as an example. Normally, I would import module `common` in this
script like this:

```py
# Script1.py

from common import method1
```

But since `script1` is part of the package and this package is imported in `app.py`
this gives an error when `app.py` loads the package:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
    import scripts.script1 as script1
  File "/home/kees/Sources/app/script/script1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from common import method1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

To solve this I changed the import in `script1.py` to:

```py
# script1.py

from .common import method1
```

Ok, this works fine. But then I thought, maybe I like to use `script1.py` as a
standalone script. For instance if I like to focus on testing just one device.
But with the new import statement, this is not possible, because when you start
`script1.py` from the commandline you get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/script1.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .common import common_method
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.common'; '__main__' is not a package
```

To overcome this problem I should go back to the initial import statement in `script1.py`.
But then the import of package `scripts` in `app` won't work anymore...

So what should I do to be able to use `script1` from the package (thus import the
package in `app.py`) and to be able to use `script1` directly. The only solution I can
think of is this (and this works):

```
# script1.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from common import method1
else:
   from .common import method1
```

But to me this does not seem a very pythonic way to do it. Another solution is not to
use a package for all the scripts, but put all the files, including `app.py`, in the same directory.
But that makes the stucture less clear. And I rather not mess with the python path.

Any suggustions? I'm curious what your thoughts are about this.